# Selecting Data From 2 Tables With Possible Duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have 81,190 town names in a tableA with the column name: TownName.

I have a list of 32,117 unique records names stored in tableB in the following way: Town, County, Volume.

I want to pick up the County for each of the 81,190 town names. So my query is as follows

```
Select TownName, County, Volume
From tableA
Inner Join tableB
On TownName = Town
Where Town = TownName
Order By TownName, Volume, County
```

All thing being equal I want to get 81,190 records back.

However, I'm getting 91,669 records. I understand why this is. A town name can appear more than once in tableB as the same town name can be in multiple counties.

An example of records returned being:

```
Abinton Limerick 0
Abinton Limerick 0
Abinton Lanarkshire 11
Abinton Lanarkshire 11
Abinton Northamptonshire 13
Abinton Northamptonshire 13
```

Abington appears twice in tableA and 3 times in tableB returning me 6 records instead on the 2 I require.

How should I modify my query so that the county with the highest volume is returned eg:

```
Abinton Northamptonshire 13
Abinton Northamptonshire 13
```

and I end up with 81,190 records.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need the county name for all the towns in tableA. So you can try with the following:

```
Select tableA.TownName, tableB.County, tableB.Volume
From tableA
left Join tableB
On tableA.TownName = tableB.Town
Where tableB.Volume= (select max(tB.Volume) from tableB as tB Where tB.Town = tableB.Town)
Order By tableA.TownName, tableB.County, tableB.Volume
```

Comment: This look like the solution - returns 77,978 rows. I'm assuming that there are some places that it isn't finding a county for. I'll check the data and update asap. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use window function MAX.
Something like:

```
Select TownName, County, Volume
From 
(Select TownName, County, Volume, max(Volume) over (partition by TownName) as highest_volume
From tableA
Inner Join tableB
On TownName = Town) as x
where Volume = x.highest_volume
Order By TownName, Volume, County
```

**EDIT**

Is this a correct way to reproduce your situation?

```
create table tableA (
TownName varchar(100)
);

create table tableB (
Town varchar(100),
County varchar(100),
Volume integer
);

insert into tableA values('Abinton');
insert into tableA values('Abinton');
insert into tableB values('Abinton','Limerick',0);
insert into tableB values('Abinton','Lanarkshire',11);
insert into tableB values('Abinton','Northamptonshire',13);
```

Comment: Error on your exact code, with correction made I still return 91,669 rows.

Comment: Which correction? I edited because I forgot a field. But I'm testing here and getting a correct answer. Could you give me some inserts so I can see if I'm doing correctly here?

Comment: where Volume = threw the error - changed it to where highest_volume = and it worked.

Comment: "It worked" you mean you got the solution or you didn't get any errors? Because I think if you try my edited comment it will work in both ways

Comment: I was expecting the right result :/
But you can bet using this window function will work (well.. I think so :D)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableC AS (SELECT DISTINCT Town, County FROM tableB);
Select  TownName, County
 From tableA
 Left Join tableC
 On tableA.TownName = tableC.Town
 Order By TownName, Volume;
```

Although i think your description is confusing. You describe "I have a list of 32,117 unique records names stored in tableB" and "A town name can appear more than once in tableB". If this is the case in TableA you have unique tawon names? If not you will always have duplicates when joining the tables

Comment: The records are unique. Record 1 Abington, Limerick 0, Record 2 Abington, Lanarkshire, 11 Record 3 Abington, Northamptonshire, 13. Unfortunately there are 3 different Abingtons and if I'm going to use on of them I want to use the one with the highest volume.

Comment: If you don't need Volume in your results it makes things simpler. I updated my question

Comment: Only returns 26,858 rows

Comment: Try to ommit "distinct" from select. What's the result?

Comment: That returns 91,669 rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL then this query must work:

```
SELECT
  a.TownName,
  (SELECT b1.County FROM tableB b1
   WHERE b1.Town = a.TownName AND b1.Volume = b.max_volume
   LIMIT 1) AS Country,
  b.max_volume AS Volume
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Town, MAX(Volume) AS max_volume
   FROM tableB
   GROUP BY Town
) b ON b.Town = a.TownName
ORDER BY a.TownName, County
```

If your database server supports window functions, then query can be simpler:

```
SELECT a.TownName, b.County, b.Volume
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Town, County, Volume,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Town ORDER BY Volume DESC) rn  
  FROM tableB
) b
ON b.Town = a.TownName AND b.rn = 1
ORDER BY a.TownName, b.County
```